# TCP File Transfer Issue

Tags: java, networking, tcp, file-transfer

I. Introduction

I am opening and reading from a file, sending chunks of data through a TCP socket as I read.

SENDER CODE

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
while ((in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    SendProtocol(new FileTransfer(sender, receiver, buffer);
}
```

RECEIVER CODE

```
if(o instanceOf FileTransfer)
    FileTransfer tf = (FileTransfer) o;
    out.write(tf.getData);
}
```

II. Problem

After I send the protocol through the TCP socket, I view the bytes being sent over. They are all unique. BUT at the receiver side, the bytes received is just the same byte[] over and over.

III. Example

```
SENDER BYTES  
[3, 3, 5, -44, 4, 3]      
[99, -3, 5, -44, 7, 3]
[-11, 3, 5, -44, 4, 7]
[10, 6, 5, -44, 4, 66]

RECEIVER BYTES
[3, 3, 5, -44, 4, 3]
[3, 3, 5, -44, 4, 3]
[3, 3, 5, -44, 4, 3]
[3, 3, 5, -44, 4, 3]
```

Comment: What is your `SendProtocol` and `FileTransfer` class? They are not standard java library.

Comment: SendProtocol is a function in my clients network class that delegates all TCP connectivity of sockets ect. Loop listening for protocols with input and output streams. My FileTransfer class is not standard java library, it is a serializable class object that contains, sender, receiver and bytes. (Is there a better way to do this O_O)?

Answer (score 2):

One problem you have is that you don't check how many bytes you recieved. It may be that you get a full buffer almost every time over loopback, but you are unlikely to get this over a real network.  You have to record how many bytes were read into the buffer and use only that amount.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this test example I did makes it clear what you have missed:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Server server = new Server(12345);

        Socket s = null;
        InputStream fs = null; 
        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
            fs = new FileInputStream("test.txt");

            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = fs.read(bytes)) != -1)
                os.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        finally {
            if (s != null)
                s.close();
            if (fs != null)
                fs.close();
        }


        server.join();
    }

    static class Server extends Thread {

        ServerSocket serverSocket;

        Server(int port) throws IOException {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket s = serverSocket.accept();

                InputStream is = s.getInputStream();

                try {

                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                        int read;
                        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) 
                            sb.append(new String(bytes, 0, read));
                    }

                    System.out.println(sb);
                }
                finally {
                    if (is != null)
                        is.close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `out.flush()` after writing all the information.

Comment: And don't forget to `out.close();` when you are done with the output stream.

Comment: I double checked that I have done both of these, so I am still puzzled why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

What's FileTransfer, and does its constructor copy the buffer?  Is its operation asynchronous?  It could be that its buffer gets refilled by the loop before it has been copied to the TCP socket.  I.e., you keep queueing up pointers to the same buffer, which you then overwrite in the loop.

Make FileTransfer assume ownership of the buffer parameter, deleting it when sent.  Then allocate a fresh one for each trip through the loop and hand it off to the FileTransfer.

Comment: I will try that. I ran my code separately, aside from the program, and it works my way, but for sure trying this.

Comment: Update: I just did a forloop and copied the buffer into a new buffer and sent it off. Is this a good way of doing it? It works.